# Prove tautology using truth trees

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hi there I have to prove some tautologies using truth trees. I am doing this by negating the expresion and then trying to find contradictions on every branch. But I can't achieve this. I can't find any contradiction. My tree finish by arriving at sample propositions on every branch. Does that mean am I doing it wrong? For example I have this expresion:

$(p\Rightarrow q) \Rightarrow ((\neg r \Rightarrow \neg q) \Rightarrow (\neg r \Rightarrow \neg p))$

And another thing: My teacher told me that I am not allowed to use rules of inference ( or at least if I use them I need to prove them using a truth table). Is this right?

Comment: If you apply it correctly to the *negation* of the above formula it works: three paths all closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you're doing it wrong from that description.  Each branch ends with a simple proposition.  You should then find that the branch contains both a simple proposition and its negation; for example, both $p$ and $\neg p$ appear in the branch.  These can be anywhere in the branch, they don't have to be at the end.

If you negate the expression you give, you should be able to construct a truth tree that has a contradiction in every branch.  The truth tree I built has 3 branches and 11 propositions in it total.

I think that what your teacher meant is that, when building a truth tree, you can only use the truth tree rules.  This is right: that's the definition of a truth tree.

Comment: Isn't this the way I should work this out: [link](http://postimg.org/image/u4sihaxor/)? 
And by the "truth trees rules" you mean those that are presented at 3:50 in this  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFgeLeewtEQ)?

Comment: I figured it out now. My mistake was that I was applying rules of inference instead of truth trees rules. Thanks for your help @Robin